# Python Memcache

Tags: python, memcached

Hello I'm new to Memcache.I have 5 Memcache servers (version 1.22) and I'm using Python memcache library.When I use one server all works fine but when I use memc.set_servers(memcL) to configure the 5 servers some keys get cached and others not. What is the cause of this strange behavior?

Code excerpt:

```
     itemsForCache=queries[1].execute(settings.getDBCursor_1(),queries[1].getQuery(settings.getParameters()))     
     cacheDataEntry="" 
     for CacheItems in itemsForCache:
         cacheDataEntry+=str(CacheItems[0])+" "

     cache_time = time.time() - start_time
     cachingTime+=cache_time;
     li.info(recommendation.getIdRec()+str(iterator[0])+"_"+pKey+" | "+cacheDataEntry+" | "+str(cache_time))
     settings.getMemCacheClient().set(recommendation.getIdRec()+str(iterator[0])+"_"+pKey,cacheDataEntry,int(settings.getConfigurationValue("memcache-data-life-time")))
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is actually not a distributed server; it's a simple key-value store. Each memcached instance running in each one of your servers functions independently, without knowing there are also other memcached servers around. Your software gives the server a key, it receives a value; and that's it.

So how is data distribution achieved? It's the client library that does this. The memcached client library (i.e. the python memcache library your program uses) is the one that actually distributes the data among all servers for which you have configured it. Its algorithm for data distribution is such that a given key will always go to the same memcached server.

So, some keys are cached, others aren't. This probably means that the keys that are cached go to a memcached server that is working, whereas keys that aren't cached go to a memcached server that is unreachable. You should verify that the client settings are correct, and also try to connect from the client to each server in turn, e.g. with

```
  nc 192.168.1.18 11211
```

where 192.168.1.18 is the memcached server.

Also note that if you change the client configuration (e.g. by adding a server), then the distribution of all keys changes, so some keys that you already cached before changing the configuration may not be retrievable in the new configuration (because the server for them has changed) and will need to be re-cached.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally the problem was that I was setting an expire time for the cached key bigger than 30 days and Memcache doesn't support expire times bigger than 30 days. That circumstance was causing the strange behavior of Memcache.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by setting the key expire time to 0 (no expiration). Memcache has a strange behavior when setting the above mentioned parameter to a value bigger than 2592000s (30 days).

From http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php:

"Expiration time of the item. If it's equal to zero, the item will never expire. You can also use Unix timestamp or a number of seconds starting from current time, but in the latter case the number of seconds may not exceed 2592000 (30 days)."

Thank you for your help.